# Loop Search for Imap / Python3 / Gmail

Tags: python-3.x, imaplib

Have a bit of a problem and hoping you can help me

What i am trying to do

1. Connect to gmail Via Imap
2. Loop through a list of subjects to search for
3. Select the id and go and download the attachment
4. got it working for 1 but when i go to run the loop through the List(searchlist)

I am getting an error

is the imaplib able to do this

```
try:
    for i in range(len(searchlist)):
        #print(str(searchlist[i]))
        print(str(searchlist[i]))
        imapSession.select('Inbox')
        typ, data = imapSession.search(None, str(searchlist[i]))
        print(data)
        if typ != 'OK':

            print('Error searching Inbox.')
            raise
```

I am not getting anything back from the print(data)

thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Sorry Meant to add not really getting an error but not getting anything back, when i pass a string of a '(SUBJECT "EXAMPLE")' it works

Comment: Hi!  Can you please show us what search list looks like?  You also don't need to reselect Inbox fr every search.  That's very expensive.  Do it once outside the loop.